# Parametrization of a figure in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces, parametrization

Considering the figure in $R^3$ defined by:

$3-cosh(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})\geq{z}\geq{cosh(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})-1}$

I want to parametrize the surface of this body.

I have studied parametrizations of circles, torus, cones... However the figure that I am trying to parametrize now is hard to imagine and not intuitive. How can I parametrize it? Is there a general method to do it?

Comment: Does $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ remind you of anything?

Comment: @rogerl Sure, a cone. But inside the $cosh$ I can't see how it would be.

Comment: I think what @rogerl is getting at is polar coordinates